# Joomla 2.5 SEO, SEF URLs with "/" gets 404 Error

Tags: .htaccess, seo, joomla2.5, virtuemart, joomla-sef-urls

Good day,

I'm not a developer or any joomla or SEO expert. Joomla's built in SEF and SEO options work fine however with virtuemart, if the product's title has a slash in it eg. `M3/M301 Coil` the urls will generate :

`site.com/category/m3/m301-coil/`

This gives a 404, if it did not have a slash it would work fine, anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Can you please tell what version of Joomla and what version of Virtuemart?

Answer (score 0):

replace slash with _ perhaps the safest and quickest resolution

Comment: Maybe, it will be better if you provide some techical things like code, rewrite rules or something